# Schedule Azure VM to turn on, run a script and turn off

Tags: azure, docker, cron, docker-compose, virtual-machine

I have a multi-container app that I need to run twice a day at specific times for about 30 mins each time. To save costs, I would like to:

1. Turn on a Linux VM on Microsoft Azure
2. Run a script that runs `docker-compose up -d`, waits 30 mins, then calls `docker-compose stop`
3. Turn off the VM

I'd love for this to happen automatically on a cron schedule.

So far, I've failed to find any Azure solution that can do all of this. Azure automation allows you to turn on/off VMs but it doesn't allow you to run a sh script on it after you've turned it on. Azure Logic apps allows you to spin up containers on a schedule but not with docker-compose.

Any idea on how I might accomplish this in a way that doesn't involve me having a VM that is always on?

Comment: Have you tried seeing if you can do this in a Function App? It's serverless and you only pay for runtime. I've never used it for this purpose but might be worth looking in to.

Comment: Run a script from your local network to automate this for you. You can even create the vm and destroy it when done. Since I automate infra with [ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/index.html), that's what I would use (since it has modules to work both with [azure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_cloud_modules.html#azure) and [docker](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_cloud_modules.html#docker)). But you have [tons of other choices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/#pivot=sdkstools&panel=sdkstools-all).

Comment: Hi @adobles96 , how's going ? Has your issue been solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No worries , you can use [this AZ powershell command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/run-command#powershell) to run sh script on your Azure VMs directly via Azure automation runbook with prarm : `-CommandId 'RunShellScript'`

For AzureRM commands , refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/invoke-azurermvmruncommand?view=azurermps-6.13.0#examples)

I have tested on my side and it works perfectly for me .

Comment: Hi @adobles96,  any assistance needed ?

Comment: Hi Stanley, yeah in the end I ended up doing something very similar but with a cron-scheduled python script using the python Azure SDK. Same idea tho.